# How can I assign an IP without DHCP enabled on the router and no static IP configuration possible on the device itself

Tags: router, ip, ethernet, dhcp

**Situation**

I have a Chromecast that I want to connect with an ethernet cable. So I've bought an ethernet to micro usb adapter. I plug the ethernet cable into my router but the chromecast will not get an IP address from the router because I've disabled DHCP on the router.

**Reason**

The reason I've disabled the router's DHCP server is because I have some IoT devices that I want to have a non changing IP, but these devices don't have static IP assignment and the router's DHCP server doesn't have IP reservation. To solve this I've configured a Raspberry PI with a DHCP server that enables me to reserve IP addresses for specific devices.

**What I've tried**

I tried enabling both DHCP servers, the Router DHCP with a very short range (100 - 101), and the Raspberry PI with large range. But this creates some strange situations where devices have trouble getting an IP address at all. (Maybe because the Router's DHCP is much quicker than the Raspberry, but the range is so limited?)

**Question**

How can I assign an IP to my Chromecast that is connected with an ethernet cable in my router where the DHCP server is disabled. (Chromecast doesn't have static ip assignment on the device itself).

Comment: Why did you enable the router's DHCP server?

Comment: Small devices that do not allow setting of Static IP are normally happy with DHCP.  Allow these devices to find their own IP and set your Router for DHCP (normal).

Comment: Aside from the obvious that you need DHCP running in your network, did you get the specific Power & Ethernet for Chromecast? If not, a "normal" USB-Ethernet adapter just plugged into the Chromecast doesn't work.

Comment: Two DHCP servers in the same network is not the solution, but is there a particular reason you can’t use the DHCP server of your RaspberryPi to provide your Chromecast with a (reserved or not) IP address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DHCP reservation will solve your problem.  Most routers support DHCP reservation.  DHCP reservation is done in your router's configuration and permanently assigns the same IP address to a DHCP client.  This means you can set all of your devices to receive dynamically assigned IP addresses via DHCP and your router will always assign them the same IP address, which you can manually assign.  Check your router's manual on how to set it up.

Note that different router manufacturers call this feature by different names.  From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Host_Configuration_Protocol):

> Manual allocation
>
> Also commonly called static allocation and reservations.The DHCP server issues a private IP address dependent upon each client's client id (or, traditionally, the client MAC address), based on a predefined mapping by the administrator. This feature is variously called static DHCP assignment by DD-WRT, fixed-address by the dhcpd documentation, address reservation by Netgear, DHCP reservation or static DHCP by Cisco and Linksys, and IP address reservation or MAC/IP address binding by various other router manufacturers. If no match for the client's client ID (if provided) or MAC address (if no client id is provided) is found, the server may or may not fall back to either Dynamic or Automatic allocation.